Amazon SQS FIFO Queue with Multi-Threaded Consumer - Ensuring Order Per MessageGroupId
I have a Spring Boot Java application that consumes messages from an Amazon SQS FIFO queue using the @SqsListener annotation. My consumer is multi-threaded, and I have maxConcurrentMessages set to 5, allowing multiple threads to process messages simultaneously.
I understand that SQS FIFO queues maintain the order of messages within the same MessageGroupId and deliver them in the correct sequence. However, I’m concerned that the multi-threaded nature of my consumer might break the FIFO processing guarantees, even though the messages are received in order.
For example, if I have 5 messages (message1 to message5) from the same group (groupA) in the queue, they are delivered in order and can all be in-flight at the same time in the consumer. Since my consumer uses multiple threads, these messages could be split across 5 different threads. My worry is that this setup could cause the messages to be processed out of order, breaking the FIFO guarantee of the queue.
My Questions Are:

Can the multi-threaded consumer potentially break FIFO processing within the same MessageGroupId, even if messages are delivered in order and are in-flight simultaneously?
What is the best way to ensure that messages within the same group are processed in the correct order, even with a multi-threaded consumer setup?
Are there any best practices, synchronization techniques, or specific configurations that can help maintain strict ordering of messages in a multi-threaded environment?

EDIT ----
I think the issue could be  that some parts of the consumer logic are async (web flux), and it is using auto acknowledgement on message success. So thread1 could pick up message1 and then go in an async block and gets acknowledged. Because message1 has been acknowledged/deleted, thread2 goes on to process message2 while message1 is still running in its async block. It might need to acknowledge messages manually or introduce some synchronicity
----- EDIT
I appreciate any insights or advice on how to manage this scenario effectively!

I think Spring Cloud simply hides too much of the AWS API from you here for you to handle this correctly. I looked at the documentation and didn't see any way to configure Spring to handle this well. I think you need to be calling the SQS API directly via the AWS SDK, without delegating that to Spring, and processing each batch of messages synchronously. You could have each thread processing a separate batch of messages, but a single batch can have multiple messages with the same group ID, so you have to process those messages synchronously if you care about the order.

The messages will be delivered to your consumer in order. However once you receive the messages, it's up to you to guarantee processing in the correct order.
From the docs:

When you receive a message with a message group ID, no more messages for the same message group ID are returned unless you delete the message or it becomes visible.

It may be possible to return messages to the queue if a particular consumer instance doesn't want to process that MessageGroupId; if you return within the visibility window it will be processed in order by some other consumer.
Alternately you could have a single consumer for the queue, which fans-out messages to the appropriate consumer. This would allow some parallel processing while enforcing that all messages within a group are processed by a single consumer serially.

Multiple consumers would never get messages with the same group ID at the same time. There will never be a batch of messages in flight with the same group id as another batch of in-flight messages. The issue is making sure a consumer processes a single batch of messages in order.
